# NULL Pointer Exception in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am learning backend with Java and I am new to Spring, ORM, template engines, and all these things. I use Spring with Mybatis, H2, and Thymeleaf. I use IntelliJ IDEA if it matters. In my home Controller, there is a NULL pointer exception that I don't know why it happens. Here is my code that I think relates to this bug. The `HomeController`:

```
@GetMapping
    public String getHomePage(
            Authentication authentication, @ModelAttribute("newFile") FileForm newFile,
            @ModelAttribute("newNote") NoteForm newNote, @ModelAttribute("newCredential") CredentialForm newCredential,
            Model model) {
        User user = userService.getLoggedinUser(authentication); // I think the problem originates here
        int userId = user.getUserid(); // NULL pointer here
        model.addAttribute("files", fileService.getAllUserFiles(userId));
        model.addAttribute("notes", noteService.getAllUserNotes(userId));
        model.addAttribute("credentials", credentialService.getAllUserCredentials(userId));
        model.addAttribute("encryptionService", encryptionService);

        return "home";
    }
```

The exception happens in the 2 lines where I try to get the currently logged-in user id. Here is my `UserService` Code:

```
public User getUser(String username) {
        return userMapper.getUser(username);
    }

    public User getLoggedinUser(Authentication auth){ return getUser(auth.getName()); }
```

And my `UserMapper`:

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = #{username}")
    User getUser(String username);
```

And my `User` POJO:

```
public class User {
    private int userid;
    private String username;
    private String salt;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // constructor and setters and getters
}
```

and my SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (
  userid INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  username VARCHAR(20),
  salt VARCHAR,
  password VARCHAR,
  firstname VARCHAR(20),
  lastname VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Finally here is the error stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.udacity.jwdnd.course1.cloudstorage.controllers.HomeController.getHomePage(HomeController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I can't find why this happens or how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related neither with Controller nor Service classes.

A not-null `Authentication` instance is successfully injected into the controller. Otherwise a NullPointerException would be thrown in the `userService.getLoggedinUser(...)` method at the moment it does `auth.getName()`.

`UserMapper` might return null in two cases:

- The `Authentication.getName()`'s method call returns `null`

  - Why? If `UserMapper.getUser(...)` receives a `null` username as argument, the query will try to match using that null. Then, unless one user has `null` as username, the `UserMapper` will return null since the database returns an empty ResulSet.
- There's no user in database that matches the given username.

I hope it might help!

Answer (score 1):

It might throw NullPointerException because Spring isn't able to inject Authentication object into getHomePage() method.

Is Authentication Object annotated with annotations like
@Component, @Service, etc.. or some other stereotype annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the stacktrace is not helpful if your snippet doesn't contain line numbers too.

How is your userService defined that you're using in the controller? Check if the instance is null, maybe it's not autowired.